# Sharepoint - fast way to detect file size by URI using REST?

Tags: rest, metadata

For SharePoint, when we want our third party Java app to access the files from within document libraries, we currently grab files using HTTP get request.

But if the file is too large, it won't work.

Is there a way to get a file's size by URI with a single rest call?

Comment: something like `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Document Library')/Files?$select=Size` ?

Answer (score 2):

The Files endpoint might be of use:

`/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Document Library')/Files?$select=Size`

When I ran it against an arbitrary library, it indicated a lot of 0 file sizes, so ymmv.

You can call an endpoint like Siddharth shows. In the results of the call I've indicated, there is an endpoint to call for the specific file. It will look something like:

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/Lists(guid'd32192c7-03b3-4a77-8156-481fb5fe4032')/files('1V-kjHLvM0-ZrgVSDNe-OtX54xS-Fz1Prx5Ucgn8azrOUaDIpwNcTY5qwu9ivln5')`

So you could call the initial Files endpoint I referenced, then depending on what you are doing, call the individual file endpoint for further information

Comment: Does that work for a single file? Please advise.

Comment: added some more information

Answer (score 2):

You can use below rest api to get file size without downloading file...

```
<yourdomain>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/path/file.ext')/Properties
```

You will get one node with below name which will return file size....

```
<d:vti_x005f_filesize m:type="Edm.Int32">1003</d:vti_x005f_filesize>
```

Answer (score 2):

This example should work:

```
${site url}/_api/lists/getbytitle('${Title Name}')/items?$select=File/Length&$expand=File
```

I can get data from `Document library`.

Note: I'm using the SharePoint online site, I'm not sure if it would work on the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the file from the HTTP headers too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263013/java-urlconnection-how-can-i-find-out-the-size-of-a-web-file